# Close mobile menu after select item in menu

Tags: jquery, angularjs, menu

i have mobile menu in my angularjs app. I want to close menu after select item from menu. I try add toggle(); but not working. Here is my jquery code. Thnx to all

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.mobile").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar").slideToggle('fast');
});
window.onresize = function(event) {
if($(window).width() >880) {
    $(".sidebar").show();
}
    else {
    $(".sidebar").hide();
}
}; 

});
```

Comment: why not use hide/slideUp,you can click a hidden menu item to use toggle??

Comment: can you put in my code what i need to do... thnx... i dont understand. I clisk on menu icon and open my menu, but after select, they dont close.

Comment: what exactly didn't you understand ?

Comment: share your HTML and CSS also

Comment: see my update https://plnkr.co/edit/Xxj1zJEhC7UQfjNZNru1?p=preview

Comment: ok, i make change in jquery like u say, and now again menu not working. Is there any change u made or only in jquery? in ur plunker, u can try to resize screen, and see that menu not open

Answer (score 0):

Change slideToggle to hide

```
$(".sidebar li a").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar").hide();//use hide here
});
```

Comment: after set like u say, menu dont work. Not open when i click on menu icon

Answer (score 0):

You can use an angular directive, and call the Bootstrap trigger function for the menu in the directive.

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',      
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

        var links = element.find('li');
        links.on('click', function(e) {
            if ($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') != 'none') {
                $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
            }
        });         
    }
};
```

})

Codepen: http://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/vKJYxo?editors=1011